# MVC4: same url base for different actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to have 2 routes similar to these:

```
routes.MapRoute("Detail", "guide/{urlname}", new { controller = "Application", action = "Detail" });
routes.MapRoute("Search", "guide/{keyword1}/{keyword2}", new { controller = "Guide", action = "Index", keyword1 = UrlParameter.Optional, keyword2 = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

So one route is a detail page that looks up an object in the database based on its url name, and the other route is a search results page based on application-generated keywords, both of which share the same url root (`/guide`). The two actions are in different controllers. Possible urls are:

```
/guide/evernote        --> should route to the application detail page
/guide                 --> should route to search results without filter
/guide/iphone          --> should route to iphone apps search results
/guide/iphone/medical  --> should route to medical iphone apps search results
```

Obviously, like this, the second route will never be matched for a url like `/guide/iphone` because the first route will already match the same url.

I don't want to do a redirect in the first action if the controller can't find the object in the database. So what other alternatives are there? Do I need to create a custom `RouteHandler` or `UrlRoutingModule` for this or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

If {urlname} is a url like it implies, you can add a constraint to test if the url matches a regex:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Comment: It is not a url, it is the unique name of the object when used as part of a url. It is not possible to make a distinction with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order and it will work:

```
routes.MapRoute("Search", "guide/{keyword1}/{keyword2}", new { controller = "Guide", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("Detail", "guide/{urlname}", new { controller = "Application", action = "Detail" });
```

Comment: No, because then a detail page will go to the search action with the object's url name as keyword1. The keywords are optional so it will match this route with only one keyword.

Comment: thats true, i removed the optionals from my answer. both keywords should be optionals? is not the same if you use query string for parameters?

example: 

guide/{urlname} for url

guide?keyword1=k1&keyword2=k2

Comment: for SEO purposes the keywords must be in the url. They are not user generated keywords, but application generated keywords.